# Groupby, counts in ranges and spread in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group `df` by "`b`" and count the number of items in different ranges.

I tried:

```
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random_integers(1, high=50, size=10), "b": ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'AAA']})
ranges = [0,10,20, 30 ]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a, ranges)).agg({'a':'count', 'b':'first'})
```

which returned:

```
           a    b
   a        
(0, 10]     2   BBB
(10, 20]    3   BBB
(20, 30]    1   AAA
```

But I want to groupby `b` thus making it the index, then "transpose" the dataframe and making the ranges new columns Expected output:

```
    (0, 10]   (10, 20]   (20, 30]
 
AAA    0          0         1      
BBB    2          3         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot table`:

```
df = df.assign(bins = pd.cut(df.a, bins=ranges)).pivot_table(index='b', columns='bins', values='a', aggfunc='count')
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
bins  (0, 10]  (10, 20]  (20, 30]
b                                
AAA         1         0         1
BBB         1         1         0
CCC         0         2         0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you only need to add a `pivot_table()` at the end of your code.

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a, ranges))\
    .agg({'a':'count', 'b':'first'})\
    .rename(columns={'a':'count'})\
    .reset_index()\
    .pivot_table(values='count', index='b', columns='a', aggfunc=sum)
```

Output:

```
a    (0, 10]  (10, 20]  (20, 30]
b                               
AAA        0         0         1
BBB        2         3         0
```

Note: Before `.reset_index()`, I had to rename the columns because your index is named `a` and it will cause an error.